# Repositories for CentOS that don't suck?

Tags: centos, repository

I'm used to using ubuntu/debian repositories and they are great. I can apt-get just about any package and it'll be there. I have not found this on centos. I called my hosting company and they suggest I install atomic turtle since it's compatible with cPanel. This didn't work when I tried to install git.

```
yum install git
...
No package git available
```

Repeat the same thing for just about any package, the default repositories are pathetic.

So perhaps there are other repositories I can use. Can anyone suggest any?

**Edit** 
The problem was cPanel excluding some git dependencies in yum.conf. See http://www.cmdln.org/2010/05/07/install-git-on-centos-cpanel-server/

Comment: I just want to comment that this is *by design*. CentOS is a rebuild of Red Hat Enterprise Linux, which includes a tailored set of packages which are given careful scrutiny. This set is getting pretty long in the tooth given how ancient (in Internet years) RHEL 5 is. RHEL 6 should address some of that in that it'll have more modern tools included (git, for example). But even then, if you want a wider world, the general answer of "add EPEL" is a good one. Or, if you want the whole universe and are willing to trade off enterprise stability, that's what Fedora is for.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

EPEL is a great repo, see the information for installing it at [the EPEL "howtouse" FAQ entry](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL/FAQ#howtouse).  In short, you would run:

```
rpm -Uvh http://download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/epel/5/i386/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm
yum update
yum install git
```

Note that EPEL does include "git".

I also use Ubuntu, and I would say a CentOS box with EPEL is quite comparable to Ubuntu with Universe for server use.

Answer (score 5):

Check out http://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories . It seems to recommend EPEL and RPMforge.

Comment: I do google things before I come here. I just wanted to get consensus on which ones are actually worth my time.

Answer (score 2):

Did you know you can still use apt-get?

Before I get to that let's answer the first question:

Dag Weers should help you:

### Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5 / i386:

rpm -Uhv http://apt.sw.be/redhat/el5/en/i386/rpmforge/RPMS/rpmforge-release-0.3.6-1.el5.rf.i386.rpm

### Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5 / x86_64:

rpm -Uhv http://apt.sw.be/redhat/el5/en/x86_64/rpmforge/RPMS//rpmforge-release-0.3.6-1.el5.rf.x86_64.rpm

### Red Hat Enterprise Linux 4 / i386:

rpm -Uhv http://apt.sw.be/redhat/el4/en/i386/rpmforge/RPMS/rpmforge-release-0.3.6-1.el4.rf.i386.rpm

### Red Hat Enterprise Linux 4 / x86_64:

rpm -Uhv http://apt.sw.be/redhat/el4/en/x86_64/rpmforge/RPMS/rpmforge-release-0.3.6-1.el4.rf.x86_64.rpm

### Red Hat Enterprise Linux 3 / i386:

rpm -Uhv http://apt.sw.be/redhat/el3/en/i386/rpmforge/RPMS/rpmforge-release-0.3.6-1.el3.rf.i386.rpm

### Red Hat Enterprise Linux 3 / x86_64:

rpm -Uhv http://apt.sw.be/redhat/el3/en/x86_64/rpmforge/RPMS/rpmforge-release-0.3.6-1.el3.rf.x86_64.rpm

### Red Hat Enterprise Linux 2 / i386:

rpm -Uhv http://apt.sw.be/redhat/el2.1/en/i386/rpmforge/RPMS/rpmforge-release-0.3.6-1.el2.rf.i386.rpm

### Red Hat Linux 9 / i386:

rpm -Uhv http://apt.sw.be/redhat/9/en/i386/rpmforge/RPMS/rpmforge-release-0.3.6-1.rh9.rf.i386.rpm

### Red Hat Linux 7.3 / i386:

rpm -Uhv http://apt.sw.be/redhat/8.0/en/i386/rpmforge/RPMS/rpmforge-release-0.3.6-1.rh7.rf.i386.rpm

### Installing Apt:

To install Apt, download the latest package for your distribution from: http://dag.wieers.com/packages/apt/. The configuration of Apt is inside the rpmforge-release package.

Comment: My opinion on it is that while you *CAN* get apt within RPM, I don't really see the need for it.  I use Ubuntu and CentOS systems pretty much equally (CentOS more for work, Ubuntu more for personal), and really prefer to use the native tool on each instead of trying to make either one feel like the other.  That's just my opinion though... :-)

Answer (score 1):

The limited set of packages in the mainline CentOS repositories comes from the design and intended audience for CentOS (and it's upstream distro Redhat Enterprise Linux). RHEL is designed with enterprise customers in mind that need a slow moving foundation, which is both stable and secure. They favour compatibility and stability of application interfaces over bleeding edge features or wide selections of software packages. The packages in the official repositories are closely maintained by Redhat to ensure they meet this requirement. Necessary security patches are ported by Redhat from newer releases into the versions included within the relevant RHEL release. This ensures compatibility is maintained whilst also ensuring security vulnerabilities are addressed in a timely fashion. If this isn't your goal, then maybe CentOS isn't ideal for your needs. As others have recommended, you can always add other repositories to get what you need, but if you find yourself doing this a lot, then maybe CentOS isn't the right tool for the job.

Comment: I would go with something Debian based if cPanel supported it.